# Get e Set em C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Estou começando a estudar C# e estou  com dúvida nos modificadores de acesso.

Qual a vantagem de usar o get e set ao invés de deixar o atributo como público? Já que com get e set eu consigo manipular ele de qualquer forma, de fora da classe? Pelo menos foi o que eu entendi, se puderem me esclarecer por favor, obrigado!